# Equilibrium of the mixture of two phases: why $U_1$ and $U_2$ depends only on $S_1,T_1$ and $S_2,T_2$?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am expecting very rigorous answer for this question if possible. Indeed thermodynamic can be very subtle and I would like to really understand the steps.

---

I consider that work only comes from pressure forces. I don't take in account number of particles for simplicity. I assume thermal and mechanical equilibrium between a system and its environment. Then, the thermodynamic potential of the problem $\Phi$ verify:

$$d \Phi = dU-TdS+PdV$$

It will decrease because of second principle until reaching a minimum for which $d \Phi = 0$. It tells us that at equilibrium we have:

$$dU=TdS-PdV$$

This is true for any system that satisfy the hypothesis I gave in the description.

**First question: do you agree with all what I wrote here ?**

---

Now, I consider a mixture between two phases. The constraints I consider are: the total volume and entropy are fixed. Thus, $\Phi=U$ the internal energy. I must minimize it.

The method is usually the following.

The internal energy is extensive:
$$U_{tot}=U=U_1+U_2$$
The total volume and entropy are fixed:
$$V=V_1+V_2, ~ S=S_1+S_2$$

We have:

$$U(S,V)=Min \left[U_1+U_2 \right]$$

Now, I must find the minimum of the quantity $U_1+U_2$ under the constraint given.

**Here is where I start to not understand the method**.

What is usually done is the following, using the constraint, I have:
$$U(S,V)=Min_{S_1,V_1} \left[U_1(S_1,V_1)+U_2(S-S_1,V-V_1) \right]$$

---

**Second question**: How do we know that the minimization is only on the independant variable $S_1$ and $V_1$. 
Said differently, how do we know that $U_1$ only depends on $S_1$ and $V_1$ (and $U_2$ only depends on $S_2$ and $V_2$). Is it an **additional** postulate we must consider ?

**Third question:** Can you tell me if the following is correct ?

Then, to conclude I will use the fact if I isolate $1$, at equilibrium I will have $dU_1=T_1 dS_1-P_1 dV_1$ (same for $2$). This is always true as given in my little introduction.

Then, I have:

$$dU=(T_1-T_2)dS_1+(-P_1+P_2)dV_1 + T_2 dS - P_2 dV$$

The minimization with respect to $S_1$ and $V_1$ implies $T_1=T_2$, $P_1=P_2$.

Comment: If as you wrote "....assume thermal and mechanical equilibrium between a system and its environment" then from the definition of the potential $\Phi = U-TS+pV$ and since $dU=TdS-pdV+\mu dN$ you have $d\Phi = dU-TdS-SdT+pdV+Vdp = \mu dN + Vdp -SdT$. Note the difference between this and what you wrote above even if you set $dp=dT=0$.

Comment: @hyportnex I don't understand what you are doing. Why do you introduce this specific potential ? I said that there is equilibrium mechanical and thermal with the environment to be able to use $P$ the pressure of the system in the work (which is the same as the external pressure), and $T$: the temperature of the system is the temperature of the thermostat. It doesn't mean they do not vary in time ?

Comment: @hyportnex maybe my sentences was confusing but my endgoal was to provide the good hypothesis giving the fact $d \Phi = dU-TdS+PdV$. If I said something incorrect with my equilibrium with environment (which I thought is a necessary condition for it) I would be happy to understand it better as well.

Comment: What are the independent thermodynamic variables of your system?

Comment: @hyportnex I guess that is a part of my question. The point is the mixing of a pure body under two phases. The total constraint are the total volume that is fixed and the total entropy that is fixed. I did not consider the variable $N$ (total number of particles, also fixed) in my question for simplicity. But this mixing is just an example (it is not my endgoal). What I want to understand are all the steps that leads to the result $T_1=T_2, P_1=P_2$ in the most rigorous manner.

Comment: You may wish to reconsider if entropy is constant when mixing two species. Why would that be the case?